# How to get data from form with unknown fields in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core, data-binding

I want to get data from my form but the number of fields are unknown.
It's like a survey. Questions fetch from database and the count may be different.

Based on the data I fetch from database, I render my html using a `foreach` and the inputs are `type='range'`

I wonder how I can get the data in my controller in the format of a key value List.

For example:

```
public class SurveyAnswer 
{
     public long QuestionId { get; set; }
     public byte Value { get; set; }
}
```

I expect to get data in my action something like this:

```
public IActionResult MyAction(List<SurveyAnswer> data) 
{
    // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question , here is a sample of using the **index** .

**SurveyAnswer.cs**

```
public class SurveyAnswer
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public byte Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; } // Index property to help with model binding
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<UnknownFields.Models.SurveyAnswer>

<form method="post" action="/SurveyAnswers/SubmitSurvey">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="data[@i].Index" value="@i" />
        <input type="hidden" name="data[@i].QuestionId" value="@i" />
        <label>@Model[i].Title</label>
        <input type="range" name="data[@i].Value" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
        <br />
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SubmitSurvey(List<SurveyAnswer> data)
    {
        foreach (var answer in data)
        {
            // Access answer.QuestionId and answer.Value or other logic
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
    }
```

[image]
[image]

If there is a misunderstanding on your question , please let me know.